# How to install Jenkins LTS 1.651.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 using Chef

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, chef-infra

I run Ubuntu 14.04 and use the [Jenkins Chef cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/jenkins).

Recently, Jenkins LTS's version 2.7.1 was released and since then my Chef cookbook for Jenkins installation started failing as it was written for Jenkins 1.x versions.

I pinned Jenkins version to 1.651.3, like this:

```
node.override['jenkins']['master']['version'] = '1.651.3'
```

But I got the error :

```
STDERR: E: Version '1.651.3' for 'jenkins' was not found
           ---- End output of apt-get -q -y install jenkins=1.651.3 ----
           Ran apt-get -q -y install jenkins=1.651.3 returned 100
```

Probably because 2.7 is the latest version. I tried following solution too but same error :

```
node.set['jenkins']['master']['repository'] = 'http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-stable'
node.set['jenkins']['master']['repository_key'] = 'http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-stable/jenkins-ci.org.key'
node.override['jenkins']['master']['version'] = '1.651.3'
```

Is there any way I can install Jenkins 1.651.3 LTS and it works for at least the next few months. That will give me the time to install and test LTS 2.7 before upgrading to it. Our Production deployment setup depends on Jenkins and I don't want to upgrade in a hurry.

Our Jenkins server is immutable and I routinely destroy and create a new one, hence the need to be able to install 1.651.3 for a little longer.

Comment: Dear _off-topic_ voter: I wouldn't consider _Chef_ off-topic for SO. You know, this DevOps thingy belongs to all of us!

Comment: @StephenKing I assume the question title did beg for a close vote  as 'tutorial request' before you edited it ;)

Answer (score 0):

As also described in [this issue](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins/issues/482), the APT repository only contains the latest Jenkins version. Therefore, you have to choose the `.war` install method by setting

```rb
default['jenkins']['master']['install_method'] = 'war'
```

This allows you to install any version.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not the answer to your question, it might solve your problem:

- Jenkins 2.0 is compatible with the 1.x line plugin and configuration-wise.
- You can easily use the Jenkins cookbook also with version 2.x by only disabling the Setup Wizard (see [this issue](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins/issues/466#issuecomment-215492115)):

  ```rb
  default['jenkins']['master']['jvm_options'] = '-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false'
  ```

I was on the same path as you were, but then just [tried that one line](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/site-chefcitypo3org/commit/967fe6fefe280c8aa466cc3316165bace4988efb) and everything just works fine also with version 2.x.